# How to peek lambda source during debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lambda

Let's say we have a property with `Func` like

```
Func<string, int> MyFuncProperty { get; set; }
```

During debug, trying to read what this lambda is/does looks like this:

[image: lambda during debug]

I only see that it's created in the same type, in method "TryUnlink", takes string and returns int. How can I peek into the source or a call that created given lambda during debug?

Checking "References" for many levels of referencing may not even tell us which one exactly is it.

Answer (score 0):

From visual studio alone you cannot do what you want. You can open your compiled library in application like illspy and find this method by name `<TryUnlink>b__15_0` it will be there in some strangely named type.

Other option for you is to convert your property to have backing field and explicit set get methods. Then set breakpoint to setter and when it hits with this particular method go up the callstack and see what actually was assigned.